# Three JS get curves on edges of cuboid (box geometry)

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I am new to three.js and I used box geometry for drawing a concrete slab! I am trying to draw waves like shapes on edges of 3D rectangular slab. My requirement is some thing like this.

[image]

I don't know if its possible to achieve above curves with box geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distort a box geometry as much as you want.

If you want waves, then use `sin` or `cos` functions:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">

import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.3/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.3/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(10, 10 ,10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var g = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(13, 5, 3, 20, 1, 1);

var p = g.getAttribute("position");
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3();
for(let i = 0; i < p.count; i++){
  v3.fromBufferAttribute(p, i);
  p.setZ(i, v3.z + Math.sin(v3.x));
}
g.computeVertexNormals();

var m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "aqua", wireframe: true});
var o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(o);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

</script>
```